# How can a Postgres trigger `AFTER UPDATE FOR EACH STATEMENT` correlate its `OLD TABLE` and `NEW TABLE`?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, postgresql-11

After upgrading from Postgres 9.5 to 11, I am trying to replace the following `FOR EACH ROW` trigger with a `FOR EACH STATEMENT` trigger which I hope would be more efficient for my specific use-case:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit_update_operations()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
AS
$$
DECLARE
    audit_user  UUID;
    data_before TEXT;
    data_after  TEXT;
BEGIN
    audit_user := coalesce(current_setting('audit.AUDIT_USER', TRUE), '77777777-0000-7777-0000-777777777777')::UUID;

    data_before := ROW (old.*);
    data_after := ROW (new.*);
    INSERT INTO dml_audit_log
    (changed_at,
     user_id,
     operation,
     table_name,
     data_after,
     data_before)
    VALUES (now(),
            audit_user,
            'U',
            tg_table_name::TEXT,
            data_after,
            data_before);
    RETURN new;
END ;
$$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I thought this was pretty easy:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit_update_operations()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
AS
$$
DECLARE
    user_id  UUID;
BEGIN
    user_id := coalesce(current_setting('audit.AUDIT_USER', TRUE), '77777777-0000-7777-0000-777777777777')::UUID;

    INSERT INTO dml_audit_log
    SELECT now() AS changed_at,
           user_id,
           'U' AS operation,
           tg_table_name::TEXT AS table_name,
           ROW (new_table.*) AS data_after,
           ROW (old_table.*) AS data_before
    FROM new_table;
    RETURN NULL;
END ;
$$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

which is called generically for every table via the following trigger:

```
EXECUTE ('
    CREATE TRIGGER trigger_audit_update 
    AFTER UPDATE ON ' || tablename || ' 
    REFERENCING 
      OLD TABLE AS old_table 
      NEW TABLE AS new_table 
    FOR EACH STATEMENT 
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit_update_operations()');
```

but an UPDATE statement triggering this function results in the following error:

```
[42P01] ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "old_table" Where: PL/pgSQL function shared.audit_update_operations() line 7 at SQL statement
```

The question I am struggling with is:

**How can I correlate the old and new rows without making any assumption about the table being changed?**

The tables I am triggering on may or may not have a primary key. Even if they do, I would not know its name or column(s) in the trigger function.

Are the rows in `OLD TABLE` and `NEW TABLE` **guaranteed** to be in the same order? I cannot rely on undocumented implementation details that may change.

Comment: In my experience the statement level triggers aren't that much more efficient than row level triggers

Comment: You cannot claim statement level triggers are more efficient than row level triggers. They essentially do quantitatively different things. More specifically in this case you cannot capture the old and new data as they do not exist in a statement level trigger. See [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: That's unfortunate. I was hoping to gain a few percent by skipping the repeated invocation. Either way, I'd like to benchmark the two variants, but for that I need a working implementation ;-)

Comment: @Belayer: but you can reference the "transition table" in a statement level trigger

Comment: The only way I can get to work, is by joining the two tables using the primary key column, e.g.: `FROM new_table nt
      join old_table ot on nt.id = ot.id` but I guess that isn't really an option for a generic trigger function;

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Interesting I did not about transition tables. Just now moving from 9.5 (to 11). I have to check this out. Thanks for the info.